# Hibernate button on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hibernate, button

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a hibernate button to the power menu of ubuntu 20.04. Online I found only solutions which require the use of the terminal.

Comment: Hello @PRATAP thank you very much for your suggestion. Could you tell me the steps I have to follow please? I'm a newbie

Comment: The steps are in the github page which is a link shown while downloading the extension from gnome-extensions website.. Infact for testing I did follow the steps from above way..

Comment: @PRATAP, time for an answer ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a extension for Hibernate Button in the Power Menu.

[Hibernate GNOME-Shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/)

[image]

Out of the box there is no effect when you click on the two items, Hibernate and Hybrid Sleep..

If you go to the Extension Homepage link provided on gnome extension website for the [Hibernate Extension](https://github.com/arelange/gnome-shell-extension-hibernate-status) you will find FAQ part on the README.md

Following the workaround from the FAQ.. copy paste the below content in the file
`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

```
[Enable hibernate in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Enable hibernate in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

Open the file with below command

```
 sudo -H gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

Copy paste the above content, save the file and close..

Reboot & Test it..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110818/discussion-on-answer-by-pratap-hibernate-button-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Comment: hI @UnKNOWn can you tell me how did you create the gif in your answer please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi it is from package `byzanz`.

Comment: I wanted to confirm this also works for XFCE in Xubuntu 22.04. The Shutdown dialog now displays Hibernate and even Hybrid Sleep. The error I was getting before this fix was `xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=FALSE`. Thank you PRATAP!