# Suspending in 22.04 leads to frozen, black screen

Tags: 18.04, suspend, 22.04, hp, integrated

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my 2022 14" HP Spectre x360. However, when I try to suspend (either from closing the laptop's lid, or from running `systemctl suspend`), the screen goes black, but the fan still runs and the power light stays on, leading me to believe it never actually suspended. Additionally, once I suspend, I cannot wake the laptop back up. I have to power down my laptop and then turn it back on again.

Most other forums suggest upgrading NVIDIA GPU drivers, but my laptop has integrated graphics (Intel). I have tried switching to xorg, which didn't work.

Additionally, I have tried booting with the following kernel: 5.15.0-40.43-generic, 5.15.0-41.44-generic, 5.18.0-051800-generic, and 5.19.3. The last three had all had the same black screen. The first one however, gave a screen with the following error messages: [Error message when suspending in 5.15.0-40.43-generic/ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNs4T.jpg)

As a last ditch effort, I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04, which had gave the same error screen as above when trying to suspend.

Edit: My (hopefully) temporary work around is mapping the hibernate key to the power button, and just hibernating my laptop whenever I plan to leave it for a while. It's kind of inconvenient, as it can take a while to both enter and exit the hibernation state, however, it's better than having my battery die all of the time. To enable hibernation, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/08/how-to-enable-hibernation-on-ubuntu.html). To map it to the power button I used the gnome extension found in the first answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260527/hibernate-button-on-ubuntu-20-04), and then I edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncommenting the line `HandlePowerKey=poweroff` and setting it to `HandlePowerKey=ignore`. Then for good measure, I set **settings**->**Power**->**Power Button Behavior**->**Hibernate**.